# Eclipse not finding a main method

Tags: java, eclipse

Firstly, I know that similar questions have been asked and answered before, however none of the solutions worked in my case.
For some reason, eclipse keeps showing a launch error saying that no main method is found despite there being a public static void main(String[] args) in my main class. Could there be an issue in the class path? I'm really unsure whats causing it.[image: Here is a screenshot of eclipse with the main method]

Comment: All of your .java files appear to be outside your `src` directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your java files under the "src" folder. Apparently they are all out of that folder and that could be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Run->Run Configurations, select your project. In the Main tab, for Main class, give class name along with complete path of the class containing main function. This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to say at the beginning of the code:

> package yourpackage;   //<----------your package is the name of the
>   package you are in

The class havent automatically put the package comment at the beginning of the Code
because like the other say your structure is false.

Yours:

> project -----> classes,src

Should be:

> project ---->src ---->package----> class

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but with different reason. I changed my java build path libraries to 15.0.1 and tried to run and it failed after that I changed them back to 11.0.2 and it worked.